# In AngularJS, Is there a global way to check if any $timeout is pending?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, timeout, protractor

I am using Protractor to test my code written in AngularJS

Probably there is some $timeout running in my AngularJS code which is making Protractor wait too long until it times out and gives error. But I am not able to figure out where in my code I am doing a continuous timeout/polling. Might be some library I am using but not sure.

Is there a global way to check in Angular how many timeouts are pending overall?

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught exception: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize
>   with the page after 10 seconds. Please see
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md

I have also tried increasing default timeout of page load from 10secs to upto 60secs which is way more than enough for my page to load. But still no success.

This also brings me to another question: What are the advantages of using $timeout over the normal setTimeout in javascript

Comment: Did you try giving `defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,` in your conf.js file? This is the one that determines the wait time of a page.

Comment: @Girish: Yes tried that. I have mentioned that in my question. After doing that i get this error :
"Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL."
I think the main problem is that somewhere some $timeout is pending, and thats what I need to find out.